# Signed Int32 из двух байт

Tags: java, c#, битовые-операции

Есть строка из Java приложения, которая формирует `signed INT` из двух байт массива:

```
final int size = array[0] & 0x00FF | array[1] << 8;
```

где, `array[0]` равно `0x08`, `array[1]` равно `0xEE`. Этот код формирует число `-4600`.

Но C# формирует совсем иное число из аналогичного кода:

```
int size = array[0] & 0x00FF | array[1] << 8;
```

Но этот код формирует число `60936`.

Подскажите, в чём соль между этими языками и как решить такую проблему.

Comment: У вас int явно разного размера. в C# int 4-х байтный. используйте что нибудь вроде Int16 а потом можете его приравнять Int32, думаю он со знаком расширит

Comment: У Java байт знаковый, у C# без знаковый. `int size = array[0] | (unchecked((sbyte)array[1]) << 8);`

Comment: @PetSerAl, спасибо огромнейшее! Я даже как-то упустил из виду о `sbyte` который и формирует знак для `short` переменной. С вашим примером всё заработало как часики.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этой строке

```
final int size = array[0] & 0x00FF | array[1] << 8;
```

значение выражения записывается в `int` (4 байта). Это значит, что все операнды преобразовываются в четырехбайтовые значения.

Расширение разрядности в Java происходит путем копирования старшего бита в исходном числе на расширяемые биты.

Итого у Вас было

```
final int size = 0x08 & 0x00FF | 0xEE << 8;
```

или в двоичном виде

```
final int size = 0000_1000b & 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111_1111b | 1110_1110b << 8;
```

теперь, что получается при расширении

```
final int size =
  0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1000b & 
  0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111_1111b | 
  1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1110_1110b << 8;
```

В c# такого копирования старшего бита не происходит. (скорее всего там приводится к типу не операнды, а итоговый результат)

Если Вы хотите на Java избежать такого расширения, то применяйте к каждой байтовой переменной операцию побитового И с 0xFF

```
final int size = array[0] & 0xFF | (array[1] & 0xFF) << 8;
```

тогда при расширении получится

```
final int size =
  0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1000b & 
  0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111_1111b | 
  (
    1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1110_1110b &
    0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111_1111b 
  ) << 8;
final int size =
  0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1000b | 
  0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1110_1110b << 8;
```