# Как использовать readInt из DataInputStream в Java?

Tags: java

Объясните, чем логически является возвращаемое значение метода `readInt()` из класса `DataInputStream`?

В javadoc используется следующее объяснение принципа работы метода: пускай a-d являются первыми четырьмя байтами. Тогда метод вернет значение `int`, эквивалентное:
`(((a & 0xff) << 24) | ((b & 0xff) << 16) | ((c & 0xff) <<  8) | (d & 0xff))`

1. Зачем тут используются конструкции вида `байт & 0xFF`? Как изменяется исходный байт после логического умножения на восемь единиц? Насколько я помню, исходный байт не изменяется.
2. Непонятно, зачем используется конструкция вида `байт | байт | байт | байт`. Для чего используется логическое ИЛИ?
3. Чем все-таки является возвращенный `int`, склеенный из четырех байтов? Логически, это же совершенно другое число. Где обычно используется этот метод?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Signed Int32 из двух байт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781295/signed-int32-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну давайте разбираться. Вот код этого метода из JDK 11.0.1 (полагаю, что он давно не менялся)

```
public final int readInt() throws IOException {
    int ch1 = in.read();
    int ch2 = in.read();
    int ch3 = in.read();
    int ch4 = in.read();
    if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
        throw new EOFException();
    return ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
}
```

Вначале тут идёт чтение четырёх байтов из `InputStream` поля `in`, которые записываются в переменные `ch1`, `ch2`, `ch3`, `ch4`. Тип этих переменных `int`, потому что таков тип возвращаемого значения метода `InputStream#read()`, несмотря на то, что на самом деле он возвращает лишь беззнаковый, то есть всегда положительный, байт в диапазоне 0..255. Тип `int` для байта излишен, но за счёт этой излишести метод `read()` может вернуть специальное значение `-1`, которое означает попытку прочитать байт после окончания потока данных. Именно это и проверяется в выражении `(ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0`. Здесь производится операция `ИЛИ` между всеми этими числами и проверяется, что результат меньше нуля, то есть, что самый левый бит равен единице. Произойти такое может только если хотя бы одна из этих переменных меньше нуля, то есть если хотя бы у одной из них самый левый бит равен единице. Если попытки чтения после окончания потока данных не было, то мы идём дальше, иначе бросаем исключение `EOFException`. А дальше нам нужно построить `int` из наших `ch1`, `ch2`, `ch3`, `ch4`, в каждом из которых по байту. Эти байты сдвигаются на соответствующие позиции и затем "склеиваются" сложением. С тем же успехом можно было бы использовать операцию `ИЛИ`. Именно эта операция `ИЛИ` используется в javadoc описании интерфейсного метода `DataInput#readInt()`, вот так: `(((a & 0xff) << 24) | ((b & 0xff) << 16) | ((c & 0xff) <<  8) | (d & 0xff))`. Операции `число & 0xff` здесь излишни. Они обнуляют все биты левее младшего байта. Но поскольку мы прочитали байты они и так равны нулю.

В итоге мы получили обычный знаковый `int`, прочитанный из четырёх байтов потока данных. Чтение происходит в порядке от старшего байта к младшему, называемом так же big-endian. Такой способ передачи данных используется при сериализации объектов Java, в протоколах TCP/IP, во многих форматах данных, например форматах изображения PNG, JPEG и прочих, в большенстве архитектур процессоров.

Существует так же обратый порядок, от младшего к старшему или little-endian. Им пользуются, например, Intel совместимые процессоры x86.

Comment: "Такой способ передачи данных используется при сериализации объектов Java, в протоколах TCP/IP, во многих форматах данных"

то есть, когда происходит склеивание четырех байтов до `int` для компьютера это не выглядит, как преобразование одного типа информации в другой? потери информации не происходит и компьютер на низком уровне все равно воспринимает этот `int` как набор единиц и нулей, и при попытке чтения восстанавливает ту же самую информацию, что и была раньше?

Comment: В языке Java `int` состоит из четырёх байтов. Если вы хотите прочитать `int` из `InputStream` вам, так или иначе, придётся прочитать четыри байта и построить из них `int`. Не понимаю, где вы тут нашли потерю данных?